# replace names using info in other variables

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file containing a list of objects in the first column and others 3 columns with 3 different but correlated variables.
The files is like this:

```
file.txt:

aaaa_111______ GCP 1 yes
bbbb_23e______ DFR 1 no
cccc_345______ TRE 4 no
dddd_65e______ WER 2 yes
eeee_456______ YTR 1 no
ffff_222______ HYT 4 yes
gggg_345______ UIY 2 no
```

I need to obtained a new file in which I change the second column (name of ligand) conidering the third and fourth column. For two objects, if the number in the third column is the same, I want to replace the name in the second column using the name of the objects which in the fourth column there is "yes".

The final file will should be like this:

```
aaaa_111______ GCP 
bbbb_23e______ GCP
cccc_345______ HYT
dddd_65e______ WER 
eeee_456______ GCP
ffff_222______ HYT 
gggg_345______ WER
```

I replaced the names of the ligands (second column) for which in the fourth column it was written "no" with the name of the ligand that in the third column had the same number and in the fourth had written "yes".
I hope I have been clear, but I do realise that the problem is complex enough to explain in words. Could someone suggest how to do that? Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

Read the file twice. On the first read, remember what numbers should be replaced by what. In the second read, replace the values based on the table you created in the first pass.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

open my $in, '<', shift or die $!;

my %replace;
while (<$in>) {
    my ($ligand, $number, $keep) = (split)[1, 2, 3];
    if ($keep eq 'yes') {
        die "Duplicate $number $ligand"
            if exists $replace{$number};

        $replace{$number} = $ligand;
    }
}

seek $in, 0, 0;
while (<$in>) {
    my ($obj, $ligand, $number) = (split)[0, 1, 2];
    if (exists $replace{$number}) {
        say join ' ', $obj, $replace{$number};
    } else {
        warn "Can't replace: $_";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I try, but where should I insert the original file on which to read the information? Excuse me but I’m not practical.

Comment: @TommasoPalomba: It should be given as a parameter to the script. `perl this-script input-file`

Comment: script_replace.sh: line 2: use: command not found
script_replace.sh: line 3: use: command not found
script_replace.sh: line 4: use: command not found
Impossibile ottenere un descrittore di file che si riferisce alla console
script_replace.sh: line 8: my: command not found
script_replace.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
script_replace.sh: line 9: `while (<$in>) {'

Comment: I obtained these message

Comment: @TommasoPalomba It's a perl script, not a shell script...

Comment: @TommasoPalomba: Then you didn't run it as I told you.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR { if($4=="yes") { map[$3]=$2} } NR!=FNR { if ($4=="no") { $2=map[$3] } print $1" "$2 }' file.txt file.txt
```

Using awk, process the file twice. On the first pass (NR==FNR), create an array when the space delimited 4th field is yes. The index being the 3rd delimited piece and the value the second. Then on the second pass (NR!=FNR), when the 4th field is no, substitute the 2nd field for the value in the map array and print the necessary data. Otherwise, just print the necessary data.

Comment: It doesn't work. It give the same result of the original files without the columns 3 and 4 but the name aren't replace

Comment: OK. What version of awk are you running? (awk -V)

Comment: Also, are the field separators actually spaces as they are in the example?

Comment: The version is: GNU Awk 4.0.2 and the separator between the columns are tab

Comment: Same version as mine and so it should work.  This solution is simply outputting to screen and not writing to the file.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is the same. The name of the object are not replace

Comment: Have you copied and pasted the solution?

Comment: yes, the scirpt is this: awk 'NR==FNR { if($4=="yes") { map[$3]=$2} } NR!=FNR { if ($4=="no") { $2=map[$3] } print $1" "$2 }' list.txt list.txt

Comment: OK. As long as the file is list.txt and not file.txt as in your example.

Comment: too much. The file list.txt has 8949 rows